# How to set weight of enpoints durin laod balancing in wso2 manager

Tags: algorithm, wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cexox.png)I have set up weighted round robin as algorithm but i can't seem to set weight to different endpoints in apim publisher, default weight of 1 is implemented how can i set their weights?

I did try adding properties in deployment.toml file to confiure weights to endpoints and looked for option to set form publisher interface.